# About "quasi-diagonal" symmetric integer matrices and their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

I have a symmetric, $\mathbb Z$-valued, invertible, quasi-diagonal (defined below*) $N\times N$ matrix $K$. There are two properties $K$ could have:

(a) $K$ can be turned into a [block-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) form by $SL(N,\mathbb Z)$ transformations of the form $K \rightarrow W K W^t $

(b) $K^{-1}$ is quasi-diagonal*

I have two questions about these conditions:

1. Does (b) imply (a)?
2. Does (a) imply (b)?

*Definition of "quasi-diagonal": A matrix $M$ is said to be quasi-diagonal if all entries that are not on the first $p$ diagonals vanish, for some $p<N/2$. For example,
$$M=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1
\end{pmatrix} $$
is quasi-diagonal because its entries vanish away from the 2nd diagonal (principal diagonal = 1st diagonal), i.e. $p=2<7/2=N/2$.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe that there should be some relationship between (a) and (b)? Is there some family of matrices that you have been considering?

Comment: We've observed these in some physics problems and we believe that this is the cleanest formalization that may be doable.

Comment: a few things. I am not sure what you mean by block diagonalizable:  is it just that we can arrange all elements off two diagonal blocks (nonzero size) to be zero? Next, some oddities. Symmetric integer matrices may always be diagonalized with rational matrices  of determinant $\pm 1.$  However, over the integers, this may not work. In particular, the Smith Normal Form,   which is of the form $A M B$  and is diagonal, need not be expressible as $ C^T M C$   with integer nonsingular $C.$   Suggest borrowing Newman, Integral Matrices, for starters.